# Building a cnn. I have weights from a github file in hdf5 format which i am Unable to load it

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

Unable to upload the weights in colab notebook.Saved in hdf5 format
Downloaded the hdf5 file in my drive in colab folder.Still not helping
It would reduce the training time for my cnn image classification model
The weights are from a github account.

```
# define hyper parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
weight_decay = 1e-6
momentum = 0.9

# define weights and build model
weights = 'all_cnn_weights_0.9088_0.4994.hdf5'
model = allcnn(weights)

# define optimizer and compile model
sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=weight_decay, momentum=momentum, 
nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics= 
['accuracy'])

# print model summary
print (model.summary())

# test the model with pretrained weights
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Error message:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-30-4b939a359e11> in <module>()
      5 # define weights and build model
      6 weights = 'weight.hdf5'
----> 7 model = allcnn(weights)
      8 
      9 # define optimizer and compile model

 4 frames
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in 
 make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
     140         if swmr and swmr_support:
     141             flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
 --> 142         fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
     143     elif mode == 'r+':
     144         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)

 h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

 h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

  h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'weight.hdf5', 
errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, 
 o_flags = 0)
```

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem. You might need to `%cd /content/drive` to get the right working directory, but it's tough to know without seeing a complete notebook.

Comment: The error you show here, you use `weights = 'weight.hdf5'`. Which probably not exit there. Is there still any problem after you change your code to what you show us here?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It's not reproducible without data.